# AMD Drivers make Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon crash

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, x-server, amd, mdm

I just installed Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon on my Samsung Series 5 netbook (dual boot with Windows 8.1, which I reinstalled myself).

The first boot worked fine but I then installed the package `fglrx-updates` for my **AMD Radeon HD 8750M**. And finally I installed the **AMD Drivers and the Catalyst Control Center** software.

Upon rebooting, the X Server didn't start and I can only use the console mode.
I removed the `fglrx-updates` package with apt-get, but I don't know how I could remove the AMD Drivers.

Can you please help me restarting my X Server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally made it to my desktop thanks to this topic : http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=137660

Just read his method starting from **"the way that worded for me!"**.

To generate the packages for **Linux Mint 17** you need to use this parameter : 
`--buildpkg Ubuntu/trusty`.

Answer (score -2):

To uninstall the AMD driver :

```
sudo aticonfig --uninstall
```

That should make it.

Comment: This is a bad idea. Unless the drivers were installed manually, they should not be removed manually. Doing so could definitely cause issues with package management.

Answer (score -4):

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```